# Pyinstaller to include selenium for firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, pyinstaller

I have a python script that runs perfectly as:

```
python myScript.py
```

but after the creation of an executable with Pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller -c -F myScript.spec
```

I got:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

The `myScript.spec`:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['mScript.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\python36\\my\\ALL'],
             binaries=[("C:\\python36\\geckodriver.exe", '.')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='myScript',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

I spent lots of time to search but did not solve the issue. Most of the posts are for chrome driver.

Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using virtual env for this?

Comment: @py_saad, no I am not using virtural env for this.

Comment: Have you tried `--hidden-import=selenium` flag?

Comment: Try this - pathex=['C:\\Python27\\Scripts', 'C:\\Python27\Lib\\site-packages'] and I see you have typo over there <a = Analysis(['mScript.py'],> to <a = Analysis(['myScript.py'],>